# why does response codes returned by httplib and urllib not match?

Tags: python, http

I'm writing a dead link detector and wondering which lib i should use, httplib and urllib, so I tried both.

```
def http_response_code(url):
    host = urlparse(url)[1]
    req = '/'.join(urlparse(url)[2:5])
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(host)
    conn.request('HEAD', req)
    res = conn.getresponse()
    return res.status, res.reason

def urllib_response_code(url):
    a = urllib.urlopen(url)
    return a.getcode()


def main():
    url = 'http://1010wins.com/content_page.php?contenttype=4&contentid=6077355'
    print http_response_code(url)
    print urllib_response_code(url)
```

But I'm confused about the mismatch of results returned by the above 2 methods, which are:

> (302, 'Found')
>   200

I think maybe it's because urllib automatically detect the redirect and fetch the final destination page, and then return the response code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`302` is the HTTP status code for a redirect (see for example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302)), and `httplib` (the lower-level library) returns it faithfully, while `urllib` is automatically following the redirect and giving you the final resulting status code (`200` for "everything OK").

Pick the library that best suits the abstraction layer you want to work at -- `httplib` gives you a lot more control, but it's less general (won't do anything with URLs with other protocols such as `ftp:`, etc, for example) and lower-level (so you have to do a bit more work!-).